# How to stop event propagation using directive?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a directive that works in other only angular application, but in Ionic with angular it doesn't.

The directive check if a user is logged, if not, open a popup with some instructions.

When a user is not logged in I have the popup and works, but the event is fired the same despite the preventDefault/stopPropagation etc.

This is the code:

**View.component.html**

```
<ion-icon name="pricetag-outline" onlyLogged authorized="true" (click)="saveNews(news)" ></ion-icon>
```

**only-logged.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { PopoverController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { OnlyLoggedComponent } from '../components/only-logged/only-logged.component';
@Directive({
    selector: '[onlyLogged]'
})
export class OnlyLoggedDirective implements OnInit {

    @Input() authorized = false;
    isUserLogged: boolean;

    constructor(private auth: AuthService, public popoverController: PopoverController) { }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    clickEvent(event) {

         if (!this.isUserLogged) {
            console.log(event);
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            event.returnValue = false;

            event.buttonDisabled = true;

            this.openLogin(event);

            return false;
        }
    }



    ngOnInit() {
        this.auth.isAuthenticated.subscribe((authenticated) => {
            this.isUserLogged = authenticated;
        });
    }


    async openLogin(ev: any) {
        const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
            component: OnlyLoggedComponent,
            event: ev,
            translucent: true,
            animated: true,
            size: 'auto'
        });
        await popover.present();

        const { role } = await popover.onDidDismiss();
        console.log('onDidDismiss resolved with role', role);
    }

}
```

Ionic Version: 6.18.1
Angular: 13.0.3
Node: 16.13.2

I made a lot of search but I didn't reach a solution... Someone can tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question I understood that you are trying to intercept a click event using `@HostListener` directive.

I actually couldn't get this requested behaviour to work using the hostlistener either.

It seems to me the problem is that `stopPropagation` in `bubbling` mode prevents event firing from child to parent.

But the thing is that you are trying to prevent click on the element itself depending on some condition.

In other words you need exactly the opposite, you need to apply `stopPropagation` in `capturing mode`, from parent to child

My proposal is to use `rxjs fromEvent` - https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/fromEvent

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Directive({
    selector: '[onlyLogged]'
})
export class OnlyLoggedDirective {
    sub = new Subscription();
    logged: boolean = true;

    constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        const el = this.elRef.nativeElement;
        this.sub = fromEvent(el.parentNode, 'click', { capture: true})
        .subscribe( (ev: any) => {
            if(ev.target == el) { this.checkLogin(ev); }
        })
    }

    checkLogin(ev: any) {
        if(!this.logged) {
            console.log("user is not logged in", );
            ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
            this.openLogin(ev);
        } else {
            console.log("user is logged in"); 
        }
    }

    openLogin(ev: any) {
        console.log('onDidDismiss resolved with role');
    }
}



<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <div onlyLogged (click)="run()">click on me</div>
</ion-content>

 run() {
    console.log("This click has to be prevented, when user is not logged     in");
 }
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, I want to prevent the click function that is on the element. The directive check the auth and if is not logged I want to avoid the execution and show a popup. With this code I show the popup but the action continue to perform. In angular works, but with ionic It doesn't

Comment: So u want the the `directive` to prevent `saveNews(news)` function when user is not logged in? i modified answer. Quick and dirty, you can reform. Tested on ionic

Comment: Yes, it's working! I'have only a little issue. If I'm logged, click, make the action and than I make a logout, popup appears. I have to debug but I think you saved my time ;)

Comment: That's great ;) Happy to be of help

Comment: @tony I've the similar usecase the difference is in this condition if(!this.logged) {
            console.log("user is not logged in", );
            ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
            this.openLogin(ev);
        }  Instead for checking variable I need to check the value that arrives from API getUser() call and inside subscribe I'm checking  and performing ev.stopImmediatePropagation();  Issue is I'm unable to prevent click, can you help me with this usecase?